# How can I programmatically determine whether new work item added to TFS using C#

Tags: c#

I need to pop up some notification when new Work item add to TFS programmatically. 
I searched lot. but couldn't able to found any relevant resources for this matter. 
please help.

Is there ay sort of filter that i can use in [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you need, but maybe you could suscribe to server events (implementing an application) and filter them to check what kind of event and what to do with it. Here you have a sample: 
[Team Foundation Server Event Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx)